# linux bind intermittent dns resolution problems

Tags: linux-networking, bind

I have intermittent problems with my dns resolution. Sometimes connection fails (and dig don't resolve too) to some nodes, other times to others, and WITHOUT ANY CONFIG CHANGE other times each one resolve correctly to IP.
The offending names are:

```
dallas1.fitsaas.com
dallas2.fitsaas.com
uk1.fitsaas.com
uk2.fitsaas.com
```

How can I check my bind config on my dns servers (ns0-ns4.fitsaas.com) for validity?
When some name is failing, what tools among dig I have to test where is trying to resolve and why is not doing it?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have a surprising number of authoritative servers for the `fitsaas.com` zone:

```
$ dig +short fitsaas.com NS
ns1.alpnames.com.
ns3.alpnames.com.
ns1.fitsaas.com.
ns3.fitsaas.com.
ns2.alpnames.com.
ns4.alpnames.com.
ns4.fitsaas.com.
ns2.fitsaas.com.
ns0.fitsaas.com.
```

As all of these are published in NS records, each of these nameservers is supposed to know everything there is to know about the `fitsaas.com` zone (except possible sub-zones, but each of these servers must at least have the delegation records for those). Each query for `fitsaas.com` domain information will be sent to one of these DNS servers effectively at random, in order to balance the load of the DNS servers.

However, it appears that only a few of those will actually be able to provide answers for me:

```
$ for i in $(seq 0 4); do echo "ns$i.fitsaas: "; dig +short dallas1.fitsaas.com @ns$i.fitsaas.com; done
ns0.fitsaas:
ns1.fitsaas:
ns2.fitsaas:
63.142.255.107
ns3.fitsaas:
63.142.255.107
ns4.fitsaas:

$ for i in $(seq 1 4); do echo "ns$i.alpnames: "; dig +short dallas1.fitsaas.com @ns$i.alpnames.com; done
ns1.alpnames:
ns2.alpnames:
ns3.alpnames:
ns4.alpnames:
```

The results for the rest of your problem names are similar: only `ns2.fitsaas.com` and `ns3.fitsaas.com` seem ready to provide answers about these names to the world.

By replacing `+short` in the `dig` command options with `+noall +answer +comments` we can get more information on what's amiss.

```
$ for i in $(seq 0 4); do echo "ns$i.fitsaas: "; dig +noall +answer +comments dallas1.fitsaas.com @ns$i.fitsaas.com || echo "error"; done
ns0.fitsaas:
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 62501
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
[...]
```

`status: REFUSED` indicates this server refused to answer my query. This is not a showstopper, as this is clearly an error and a DNS resolver will just ask another authoritative DNS server. The other uncooperative `ns*.fitsaas.com` nameservers seem to respond the same way.

However, the `ns*.alpnames.com` nameservers will answer differently:

```
$ for i in $(seq 1 4); do echo "ns$i.alpnames: "; dig +noall +answer +comments dallas1.fitsaas.com @ns$i.alpnames.com; done
ns1.alpnames:
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 23895
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available
[...]
```

`status: NXDOMAIN` means "I am sure such a DNS name doesn't exist." This is a showstopper: when an DNS server that is authoritative for a given zone says that a particular name does not exist in that zone, *that is not an error*: it is a valid answer, although a negative one. Negative answers are even cacheable, although usually for shorter times than positive ones.

Once a resolver gets a negative answer from a DNS server that is authoritative for the requested domain, it must take it as gospel truth: there is no such name. Since all authoritative servers for a given zone are supposed to have full and current knowledge of the zone, asking a second opinion from another authoritative server is supposed to be just a waste of time and resources.

Are the `ns*.alpnames.com` servers supposed to be authoritative for your zone? If not, contact your DNS registrar and have them removed from the delegation NS records. Since these delegation records are at the level of the `.com` TLD, you cannot do this just by editing the NS records in your authoritative DNS server(s).

As `ns0.fitsaas.com`, `ns1.fitsaas.com` and `ns4.fitsaas.com` seem to be refusing external queries, you should consider removing those from the delegation NS records too - they seem to be unwilling to serve the public, so there should be no point in mentioning them in the delegation.

Comment: It looks like you have a surprising fast response time and good knowledge, thanks.  So, the random function depends on which ns server is reached everytime. I'll try to configure equal nsX.fitsaas.com, the problem was that I don't know how to not depend of alpnames ns servers...

Comment: According to WHOIS information, Alpnames seems to be your DNS registrar. So either the ns*.alpnames.com servers are not receiving fitsaas.com updates when they should, or they are unnecessarily listed in fitsaas.com domain delegation and should be removed. In both cases you should contact Alpnames somehow. Most registrars today have a web interface that can be used to update the delegation information.

Answer (score 1):

See http://dnsviz.net/d/fitsaas.com/WkFcPg/dnssec/  , this domain has many errors, some namservers are not replying correctly (besides the fact that there is a discrepancy between the NS RRSET at registry and on the authoritative nameservers of the domain):

```
fitsaas.com zone: The server(s) responded over TCP with a malformed response or with an invalid RCODE. (37.247.116.68, 63.142.255.107)
fitsaas.com zone: The server(s) responded over UDP with a malformed response or with an invalid RCODE. (37.247.116.68, 63.142.255.107)
fitsaas.com/A: The response had an invalid RCODE (REFUSED). (37.247.116.68, 63.142.255.107, UDP_0_EDNS0_32768_4096)
fitsaas.com/DNSKEY: The response had an invalid RCODE (REFUSED). (37.247.116.68, 63.142.255.107, UDP_0_EDNS0_32768_4096, UDP_0_EDNS0_32768_512)
fitsaas.com/MX: The response had an invalid RCODE (REFUSED). (37.247.116.68, 63.142.255.107, UDP_0_EDNS0_32768_4096, UDP_0_EDNS0_32768_512)
fitsaas.com/NS: The response had an invalid RCODE (REFUSED). (37.247.116.68, 63.142.255.107, UDP_0_EDNS0_32768_4096)
fitsaas.com/SOA: The response had an invalid RCODE (REFUSED). (37.247.116.68, 63.142.255.107, TCP_0_EDNS0_32768_4096)
fitsaas.com/SOA: The response had an invalid RCODE (REFUSED). (37.247.116.68, 63.142.255.107, UDP_0_EDNS0_32768_4096)
fitsaas.com/TXT: The response had an invalid RCODE (REFUSED). (37.247.116.68, 63.142.255.107, UDP_0_EDNS0_32768_4096)
```

You can also use the Zonecheck online tool. Your first course of action should be to make sure that the delegation is correctly done, that is configure the same RRSET at parent (see your registrar) and in the nameservers itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [IntoDNS](https://intodns.com) to identify any configuration problems as shown to the outside world, but my guess would be that one or more of your name servers isn't responding correctly to queries.